# "The message exceeds the maximum supported size" while fetching attachment using outlook rest api

Tags: python, outlook, exchangewebservices, office365api

I am trying to fetch the attachment using outlook rest mail api but it is giving 400 rest response -

```
Response Code: 400 Text:{"error":{"code":"ErrorMessageSizeExceeded","message":"The message exceeds the maximum supported size., The message exceeds the maximum supported size."}}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates the attachment exceeds the maximum size that is set.

To resolve for *Outlook*, you need to increase the value of `maxAllowedContentLength`, `maxRequestLength` and both instances of `maxReceivedMessageSize` by editing %ExchangeInstallPath%ClientAccess\Owa\web.config

You will need to restart IIS after.

For more information see [Configure client-specific message size limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/configure-client-specific-message-size-limits-exchange-2013-help#exchange-web-services)

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Does it mean that my outlook account can receive the attachments of any size but I can't fetch it using outlook rest api because of server api limits? 
Do we have maximum attachment size limit also for outlook user? And if yes then how to increase both. Please Help